# Azure API Management: Multiple send-request from JArray

Tags: azure-api-management

I would like to iterate through payload array and send individual send-request based on each item within the payload (context.Request.Body). Has anyone else managed to get this working?

e.g. the following would send 2 requests to the end-point.

```json
[
   {
      "Identifier":"3e3b6f85-eea9-4775-905a-9e5febe2db05",
      "Created":"2020-03-17T13:53:36.4771218Z"
   },
   {
      "Identifier":"a0cfe066-3a95-4815-80df-b6c3baf3607c",
      "Created":"2020-03-17T13:53:36.4772161Z"
   }
]
```

Comment: I would suggest rather than doing it in apim do it inside a logic app. can you tell us what you are trying to achieve by sending multiple requests?

Comment: You could parse context.Request.Body - but for the moment I see no looping capability in policy expressions. This means you would need a fixed stack of <choose> and <send-request> or <send-one-way-request> expressions, which decides to fire if array index 0, 1, 2, 3, ... has an element.

Comment: @MandarDharmadhikari thanks for the reply I suspected that would be the case.

Comment: You could also do it inside a function, check out javascript inline code (preview)